# Shell script: whole directory to the remote ftp server

Tags: shell-script, ftp

I am trying to `ftp` some recording files to a remote server for backup every night. I am very confused regarding shell script.

My question / problem is : I want to move the whole folder/directory instead of file to the remote server.

Here is current script:

```
HOST='10.113.68.50'
USER='sms'
PASSWD='Abc123451'
LOCALPATH='kmpy/unica/Campaign/partitions/partition1/CiktiDosyalari'
FILE=*.sms
DIR='SMS/'

ftp -n $HOST <<EOF
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd $DIR
lcd $LOCALPATH
put $FILE
quit
exit;
EOF
```

Comment: If you can then use sftp or scp, you will need a ssh server on the remote machine. sftp and scp are more secure, and easier to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `mput *` instead of `put` to upload all of the files in the directory. Further you can screen files, for example: `mput *.jpg` will transfer all and only `jpg` files.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SCP instead of FTP. SCP is more secure, and a part of SSH. As long as your public key is in the external hosts authorized_keys-file, then you can just do something like:

```
scp -r kmpy/unica/Campaign/partitions/partition1/CiktiDosyalar/ sms@10.113.68.50:/sms/
```

Some reason why you chose FTP?

Comment: Agreed. Unless you do not have control over the remote site and you have no option but to use ftp, then configure your systems to use scp and sftp instead.

Comment: Yeah. He may need to upload his stuff on a server that offers FTP only?

Comment: I don't understand why people keep suggesting SSH when the question is FTP. There **are** a lot of situations when ssh is not available.